# Mixture of RTL and LTR in windows file name

Tags: c#, windows, filenames, right-to-left

I am trying to write a file to disk (in Windows) that contains both RTL (right to left) and LTR (left to right) text.

The filename is composed from different bits of data eg:

```
{data_part1} - {data_part2} - {data_part3} - {data_part4}.{extension}
```

Any of the data parts could be RTL or LTR.

What I have noticed is that if data part2 is RTL and data part3 is numeric, data part 2 appears in the position where data part 3 should be and also causes data part 3 to be printed RTL.

If data part 3 is non-numeric (ie a word such as 'hello') this problem doesn't occur.

However, if I copy that file name and paste it into word it appears correctly?

Which implies that Windows explorer is not displaying the text correctly

I have tried using the POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING character but that hasn't made a difference.

Has Anyone else had this issue and does anyone have any ideas of getting around it?

Comment: Is there no alternative naming scheme that would eliminate this mixture? If such mixed strings are hard to deal with by a developer, they are going to completely mess with your users and potentially other applications that might have to deal with your unusual filenames.

Comment: I believe you can achieve consistent display of these names if you put LRM before each `-`.

Comment: @spender I do agree that it isn't ideal however. It's data returned from an API that populates some of this positions sometimes it's English sometimes it's Arabic so there isn't much that can be changed I'm afraid

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks I'll give that a try shortly

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = '\u200E'+ dataPart1+ '\u200E'+ dataPart2+ ... '\u200E'+ dataPart4+ extension
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?